# Why does cherry-pick always result in a merge conflict?

Tags: git

I'm cherry picking specific commits from a release branch into my local working copy.  Every time I cherry-pick a commit from the release branch I get a merge conflict which I have to resolve, even with changes that seem trivial, such as:

```
-const char kApplicationVersion[] = "Develop";
+const char kApplicationVersion[] = "Release";
```

being the only change made in the commit to main.cc.

`git status` shows

```
You are currently cherry-picking commit 6f04be8.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:      src/appMain/main.cc
```

Why is there always a conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because since the two branches have diverged:

- dev branch has modified the line with `const char kApplicationVersion[] = "Develop";`
- rel branch has modified the line with `const char kApplicationVersion[] = "Release";`

A cherry-pick will resolve the merge against the common ancestor, but won't create an actual merge for that file (meaning the common ancestor remains a much older version, where `dev` branch started from `release` branch)

The next cherry-pick will consider the same old common ancestor and will trigger the same merge conflict.

See (much) more at "[In a Git cherry-pick or rebase merge conflict, how are BASE (aka “the ancestor”), LOCAL, and REMOTE determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058070/6309)"

Comment: So how do you fix it?

Comment: By resolving the conflict.